# Liquibase dropFirst with postgis

Tags: spring, postgis, liquibase

I'm trying to add postgis extension to my postgressql database through Liquibase, here's how I've done it :

```
<sql>CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;</sql>
```

It works fine, problem is when I'm developing I want my database to be reset every time I restart my web server, so I've set liquibase in spring like this

```
@Bean(name = "liquibase")
@DependsOn("dataSource")
@Profile("dev")
public SpringLiquibase liquibaseDev() {
    SpringLiquibase springLiquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    springLiquibase.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
    springLiquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:liquibase.xml");
    springLiquibase.setDefaultSchema(this.environment.getProperty("jdbc.defaultSchema"));
    springLiquibase.setDropFirst(true);
    return springLiquibase;
}
```

And so Liquibase tries to drop everything, including postgis views, at startup. Which lead to this err

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot drop view geography_columns because extension postgis requires it
>    Indice : You can drop extension postgis instead.

But how I'm supposed to tell liquibase to drop extensions before dropping everything else? Is there a way to tell Liquibase how to drop a database?

Versions I'm using :

- Spring IO 2.0.7
- Liquibase 3.4.2 (version set by Spring IO)
- Postgres 9.5

Comment: I believe liquibase does not know about extensions in postgres and therefore does not drop them. Liquibase will try to find all objects in the schema you are using, then build a list of drop statements and execute it. Maybe it helps when you add a schema declaration to your create extension statement like `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis SCHEMA public;` - but that is just a guess in the wild and might not make a difference...

Comment: As `public` is the default schema, it is already added to this one. Yeah, liquibase seems to be unaware of postgres extension, so it seems we have to resort to some other alternative to manage that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved this by adding a little bit of SQL that is executed before Liquibase starts :

```
@Bean(name = "liquibase")
@DependsOn("dataSource")
@Profile("dev")
public SpringLiquibase liquibaseDev() {

    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(this.dataSource().getConnection(), new ClassPathResource("delete-postgis.sql"));

    SpringLiquibase springLiquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    springLiquibase.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
    springLiquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:liquibase.xml");
    springLiquibase.setDefaultSchema(this.environment.getProperty("jdbc.defaultSchema"));
    springLiquibase.setDropFirst(true);
    return springLiquibase;
}
```

with file src/main/resources/delete-postgis.sql being

```
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS postgis;
```

That's not fancy, but it works.